# How can I find the master of a network interface in Linux

Tags: ip, network-interface

I need to read the master of a network interface from a bash script.

For example, I have these two interfaces...

```
$ ip link show tap0
4: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:3f:96:13:02:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$ ip link show br0
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:75:ad:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Given the name of an interface I need to find the master of that interface, so `tap0` -> `"br0"` and `br0` -> `""`

I can parse the output of `ip link show`...

```
ip link show tap0 | head -n1 | sed 's/.*master \([^ ]*\).*/\1/' | grep -v " "
```

which outputs `br0` (or nothing if I replace `tap0` with a device that has no master)

But I would prefer a more robust way of reading this information. Is there some kind of procfs style way to read this? Or a command that can output just the master of an interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script that gathers this information by doing the following (which is probably what `ip` and `ifconfig` do)

- Go to `/sys/class/net`
- There are symbolic links to all network adapters in the sysfs filesystem.  Ones corresponding to physical hardware are symlinked to `../../devices/pciXXXX:XX/...`, others are symlinked to `../../devices/virtual`.
- If you `cd` to one of the virtual ones, there is a `master` symlink that points to that interface's master.  If there is no master this probably won't exist.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Could add an example of how to get the master name in bash. Perhaps: `interface_master(){ [ -e /sys/class/net/$1/master ] && basename $(readlink /sys/class/net/$1/master); }` which gives the desired mapping - as per my example; `$ interface_master tap0 # prints br0` `$ interface_master br0 # prints nothing`

Comment: There is nothing, no `master` symlink at all. i'm on Debian 10

Comment: Might have changed since `systemd` or something like that.